# Verify if fcm token belongs to an android or ios device

Tags: android, ios, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have many fcm tokens in the database. I want to differentiate them based on whether the fcm token was created from an android device or an IOS device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following might help you to customize notification messages based on the platform:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message#customize-messages-across-platforms

If you want to distinguish the tokens manually, then a possible hack would be to add the platform name as a prefix when storing tokens in a database from your frontend app. Then, you can filter out the tokens on your backend by implementing a programming logic i.e. creating separate arrays for android and IOS tokens.

I don't think there is a way to just see the token and tell from which platform it belongs.